# Feature Selection algorithm/library for CRF

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection, sequential-pattern-mining

I am using the Conditional Random Fields [CRF suite scikit-learn](https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) wrapper algorithm. I have read on the literature various approaches for feature selection, but I cannot find any on that package or, generally, available ones for CRF. Would you know any libraries (Python preferred) or easy to implement algorithms for this purpose?

---

**Update**

I tried using the scikit-learn feature selector's library but does not work for 2 reasons: 1) the CRF takes as an input list of lists of dicts whereas the other take tabular data 2) the CRF does not have a `.coef` or a `feature_importances_` attribute in order to perform feature selection.

Answer (score 0):

Since sklearn-crfsuite provides a scikit-learn compatible estimator, any [scikit-learn feature selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) class that takes an estimator could work.

Comment: I tried, but I believe the type of data crashes the sklearn's selectors. That's because the CRF wrapper takes as an input nested lists whereas the sklearn selectors expect some sort of tabular data such as a numpy array. Then I believe if I convert my data into an  tabular array the CRF will not work...